# Dealing with DateTime using "Linq Methods"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[ASP.NET 4.0 / EF 4.1]

Hi,

I´m trying to use "Linq Methods" to filter a datasource based on datetime fields, but I´m getting the error: "Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context".

I know that Entity Framework have some limitations when dealing with dates, but what I need is some elegant solution to deal with this issue.

My code is:

```
    public IList<Order> GetOrders(int? orderId = null, string customerId = null, int? employeeId = null, DateTime? orderDateFrom = null, DateTime? orderDateUntil=null, DateTime? requiredDate = null, DateTime? shippedDate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<Order> result;

        result = from order in ctx.Orders.Include("Order_Details")
                 select order;

        // Apply filters to the base query
        if (orderId != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderID.Equals(orderId));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerId))
            result = result.Where(o => o.CustomerID.ToUpper().Equals(customerId.ToUpper()));

        if (employeeId != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeId));

        if (orderDateFrom != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= orderDateFrom);

        if (orderDateUntil != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderDate <= orderDateUntil);

        if (requiredDate != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.RequiredDate == requiredDate);

        if (shippedDate != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.ShippedDate == shippedDate);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

When the code executes the query (result.ToList()) it throws the exception. If I remove the datetime .Where clauses, it works fine.

Thanks!

## Solution

I have changed my code to:

```
    public IList<Order> GetOrders(int? orderId = null, string customerId = null, int? employeeId = null, DateTime? orderDateFrom = null, DateTime? orderDateUntil=null, DateTime? requiredDate = null, DateTime? shippedDate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<Order> result;

        result = from order in ctx.Orders.Include("Order_Details")
                 select order;

        // Apply filters to the base query
        if (orderId != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderID.Equals(orderId.Value));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerId))
            result = result.Where(o => o.CustomerID.ToUpper() == customerId.ToUpper());

        if (employeeId != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.EmployeeID == employeeId.Value);

        if (orderDateFrom != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= orderDateFrom.Value);

        if (orderDateUntil != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.OrderDate <= orderDateUntil.Value);

        if (requiredDate != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.RequiredDate == requiredDate.Value);

        if (shippedDate != null)
            result = result.Where(o => o.ShippedDate == shippedDate.Value);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

If someone has a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Huh, must be a 4.1 issue because 4.0 supports dates in this fashion; we have date checking just like yours and it works fine.  Are you using code first?

Comment: I can't remember, does `DateTime.Compare(t1, t2)` work in EF linq queries?

Comment: Comparing DateTimes as in the code above also works in EF 4.1. It's strange. Do you use SQL Server? Or SQL Server CE version? Or some other DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a nullable type DateTime? in your example. I'm not sure if your database column allows NULL, but I'd use `date.Value` to pass the value of the parameter to be sure EF doesn't fall over it. Note that with nullable types, you can als use the `HasValue` property to check if your parameter contains a proper value. This results in:

```
if (orderDateFrom.HasValue)
   result = result.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= orderDateFrom.Value);
```

Comment: This looks cleaner, true. But comparison with a nullable type actually works, also in LINQ to Entities. I just tested all 4 combinations (`OrderDate` and `orderDateFrom` nullable or not) and it always worked in my example, I never had to use `.Value`.

Comment: Thanks @Bart. It was really my fault, because I cannot use expressions like result = result.Where(o => o.OrderID.Equals(orderId)). I must use the expression result = result.Where(o=>Equals(orderId.Value)).
So as far as I understant, the problem relates not only to DateTime (see OrderID), but comparisons with referenceType.

Comment: @Slauma, could you provide some code excerpt that demonstrates your affirmation? Tks.

Comment: @rperson: I see now, I also get indeed your exception when I use `Equals` with a nullable type. Are you sure that this wasn't your *only* problem? Do you really also get the exception when you remove now `.Value` from your DateTime filters? (My example is really exactly like one of your DateTime Where-clauses, just with other class and property names.)